# How can vector space $V\subsetneq W$ but $V\cong W$, where $V$ and $W$ don't have finite dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$ and $W$ two vector spaces. If they have finite dimension, then $V\subset W$ and $V$ and $W$ have same dimension will imply that $V=W$. But I heard that in infinite dimensions, this doesn't hold anymore in the sense that you can have that $V$ is a proper subspace of $W$ (i.e. $V\subsetneq W$) and $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic. Could someone explain this fact please ? Because I really don't understand how is this possible.

Comment: Does it bother you to say that a square inside a square is similar to the larger square?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional vector space with basis $\{v_1,v_2,\dots\}$ and $W$ the subspace spanned by $\{v_2,v_3,\ldots\}$. Then $W\subsetneq V$ since $v_1\notin W$, but the linear map $T:V\to W$ given by $T(v_i)=v_{i+1}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Pierre If this satisfies you please accept it. You can also upvote it and other answers too.

Comment: It's very surprising that two different spaces can be the same... Moreover, for the injectivity, it looks strange : T(v)=0 implies $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \lambda _iT(v_i)=0$ but the infinite sum looks strange... what does it mean in this context ? What is the topology ?

Comment: There are no infinite sums or topology here. In order to introduce that, you need to take the completion of $V$ with respect to some norm.

Comment: @Pierre Recall that, by definition, to say that $\{v_1,v_2,...\}$ is a basis means that any $v \in V$ can be written as a *finite* sum $v= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i v_i$. There is not a canonical topology on an infinite dimensional vector space (in contrast to the finite dimensional case), and hence there is no canonical notion of infinite summation.

Comment: What do you mean by canonical ? For example, on $\{(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}\mid x_i\neq 0 for\ finitely\ many\ i\}$ has a canonical notion of summation, no ? Also, on a space s.t. $\ell^p(\mathbb R)$, we have a natural summation, no ?

Comment: @Pierre yes, but the $\ell^p(\mathbb R)$ differ for different choices of $p$, when convergence of the sums is considered. So in general, whether an series converges in the vector space, depends on the topology (or norm).

Comment: @Pierre Also, if you consider $\{(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}\mid x_i\neq 0 for\ finitely\ many\ i\}$ as a vector space, with cooridinatewise convergence, then most infinite sums would not lie in it. For example, think of a sum where every $n$-th summand is only nonzero on the $n$-th coordinate.

Comment: @Pierre In my mind, "canonical" would mean "induced naturally by the already existing structure". In a finite dimensional vector space, every choice of norm induces the same topology, so one can argue that the vector space structure naturally gives a choice a topology. In the infinite dimensional case, there is no "canonical" topology because different norms now induce different topologies, so one does not emerge naturally *just from the fact that it's an infinite dimensional vector space*. In your examples, you are invoking structure beyond this.

Comment: The definition of an object like a vector space basis has to be applicable to *all* vector spaces, so the fact that there seems a natural choice of infinite summation in *some* vector spaces is not sufficient for the generic definition to make sense.

Answer (score 3):

A standard example is with the space of real polynomials $\mathbb{R}[x]$. If  you define a map $T:\mathbb{R}[x]\to \mathbb{R}[x]$ by $p(x)\to p(x^2)$ then it is an isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and the image of $T$. However $T(\mathbb{R}[x])$ is a proper subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Vector spaces (for example over $\mathbb{R}$) are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension. The dimension is the cardinality of any basis.

Now let $V = R^\mathbb{N}$. Take any strict infinite subset $B'$ of the canonical basis $B$ of $V$ (for example, just remove one basis element). Then $|B'| = |B|$ so $V \cong \operatorname{span}(B')$

Comment: You are claiming that if two vector spaces have the same dimension, then they are isomorphic. I doubt very much that this is true!

Comment: @TonyK Why are you doubting this? It's perfectly correct.

Comment: @TonyK take a bijecion between their basises and extend linearly to get an isomorphism.

Comment: @ArnaudD.: only if they are over the same field.

Comment: @TonyK I considered that as implicitly given. (Otherwise it wouldn't make sense to say they are isomorphic.)

Comment: @ArnaudD.: Yes, OK. I could claim that the OP should have said "Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a field $\Bbb F$", but I accept that this is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example: let $K$ be a field,$W=K[X]$ and $V$ the ideal generated by $X$, $XK[X]$. You have an isomorphism:
\begin{align}
V&\longrightarrow W,\cr
X F &\longmapsto F
\end{align}